# Save Desktop shortcut position without any third-party tools

Tags: windows, display, windows-registry, icons, desktop

I have searched the web for a while now and didn´t find any (at least from what I could test - if correctly) working method.

The topic was already discussed here with good background info [Where does Windows store icon positions?](https://superuser.com/questions/625854/where-does-windows-store-icon-positions)

Nevertheless

I tried to save the mentioned keys (eport them as .reg files) rearange the icons and then see if they restore their previously "saved" positions when importing the reg files.

No luck so far.

I need this solution for an environment where third party tools which can save and restore the position of the icons are not allowed. - The User should be able to restore "his/her setting" by simply importing the reg file.

How to make it work? If anybody knowing the solution could help me it would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Short and simple: How to make it work.

Comment: Edit your question and be specific (it) isn’t specific.

Comment: Well I did it, thanks for the hint I though it was obvious