# Where does Windows 10 (1703+) store the Desktop icon positions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, icons

Does somebody know where recent versions of Windows 10 store their Desktop icon positions?

I already found this question: [Where does Windows store icon positions?](https://superuser.com/questions/625854/where-does-windows-store-icon-positions) - however this only works for older Windows 10 releases. Since version **1703** there seem to be some new registry values, especially the **IconLayouts** binary values - and the old **itemPosXXXxXXXxX** disappeared. - See this Technet thread: [Explanation of itempos and iconlayouts registry values](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2cdbc3e4-ac68-4053-82f8-e12c27b0c59a/explanation-of-itempos-and-iconlayouts-registry-values?forum=win10itprogeneral) - However it does not contain a solution on how to "export" and "import" the icon positions. And just exporting and importing the well-known registry keys does not work.

It's simply to add some required icons to a user profile at a defined position (Version 1809 LTSC). In detail, there are just pre-defined icons without any changes by a user. I can live with the icons just being squeezed into the upper left corner of the Desktop, but having them at some more intuitive positions would be a nice-to-have feature.

Answer (score 0):

As for now without finding any appropriate answer in the web, I still have to admit, there is not built-in solution.
And therefore may previous statement seems to stay valid:

Since version **1703** there seem to be some new registry values, especially the **IconLayouts** binary values - and the old **itemPosXXXxXXXxX** disappeared. - See this Technet thread: [Explanation of itempos and iconlayouts registry values](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2cdbc3e4-ac68-4053-82f8-e12c27b0c59a/explanation-of-itempos-and-iconlayouts-registry-values?forum=win10itprogeneral) - However it does not contain a solution on how to "export" and "import" the icon positions. And just exporting and importing the well-known registry keys does not work.